# Pop up minicart when I add a product to the cart magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, popup

I'm using magento 2.0.7, and what I'm trying to do is to popup the cart(the top right cart ajax minicart) when I add a product to it, Basically trigger it. I have tried to add the "showcart" class to my add to cart button classes, but if I do so, the button just opens the cart, and doesn't add the product anymore..

Answer (score 41):

This is my first answer on this site. I've been struggling trying to make this work for the past two days and I was finally able to make it work, so I though it would be nice to share it.

First of all you need to create a module:

- registration.php
- etc/module.xml
- view/frontend/layout/default.xml
- view/frontend/templates/minicart_open.phtml
- view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart_open.js

**Step 1.** You need to add a template to the site. The way to do that is by using the default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
  <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="minicart.autoopen" template="Company_ModuleName::minicart_open.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

**Step 2.** Then inside minicart_open.phtml we need to call our js file (component) by attaching it to the parent div of the minicart. In this case, [data-block='minicart']. See [this link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html) for more details.

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
     "[data-block='minicart']" : {
        "Company_ModuleName/js/view/minicart_open" : {}
     }
}
</script>
```

**Step 3.** And finally, inside minicart_open.js, the magic code:

```
define(["jquery/ui","jquery"], function(Component, $){
    return function(config, element){
        var minicart = $(element);
        minicart.on('contentLoading', function () {
            minicart.on('contentUpdated', function () {
                minicart.find('[data-role="dropdownDialog"]').dropdownDialog("open");
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Basically this code extends the functionality of the file `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js`, and it says that once the AJAX call is completed (contentUpdated), the minicart should be opened.

And that's it, a simple task with a lot of theory behind. Hope it helps.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Tks!

Comment: Seems a good fix, why does this need to be a module? Wouldn't making those changes in your theme have the same effect?

Comment: In addition to the answer above from @pinicio:
Note that the solution will only work if ajax is used for the add to cart function: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125681/ajax-add-to-cart-button-in-product-detail-page-magento-2

Comment: It works on cart update as when we add product it works but it should not work when we remove item from cart. but its working at that time also.

Comment: If i try deleting an item from the mini cart, item is not deleting..ie) once i click on the delete icon, only after the page refresh, the deleted item is getting refleted

Comment: i tried this but no pop is shown when clicked on add to cart. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/192117/show-pop-up-when-click-on-add-to-cart-magento-2

Comment: @pinicio is theer any way to reload the mini cart with ajax ? My minicart not getting updated after i added products but in cart everything ok

Comment: Hi, What to use in etc/di.xml, without that file the code is not upgrading getting error

Comment: this one is working but when you add 2 or more than items it hangs your system. I checked in js code it's called many times after item add to cart. anyone have facing issue like that?

Answer (score 7):

It can be done by simply modifying minicart.js file.

Navigate to `vendor/magento/Magento_Checkout/view/web/js/view/minicart.js`

Under initialize: function, you will see

```
$('[data-block="minicart"]').on('contentLoading', function (event) {
```

Replace the function with this code.

```
$('[data-block="minicart"]').on('contentLoading', function (event) {
            addToCartCalls++;
            self.isLoading(true);
            $('[data-block="minicart"]').on('contentUpdated', function ()  {
                $('[data-block="minicart"]').find('[data-role="dropdownDialog"]').dropdownDialog("open");       
                setTimeout(function() {
                $('[data-block="minicart"]').find('[data-role="dropdownDialog"]').dropdownDialog("close");
            }, 4000);
            });
        });
```

You can change the timeout as per your requirement.

upload the file and clean cache by running the command

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Cheers!

Comment: i tried this one but not worked , i flushed the cache

Comment: Make sure you have no override of this file
vendor/magento/Magento_Checkout/view/web/js/view/minicart.js
under your theme.

Comment: You should never change the core files directly. Instead, change it within your theme or a custom module.

Comment: Glad it helped you :)

Comment: I tryed this method, and works fine on Android and Windows Mobile, but on iPhone, it opens the cart popup, but can't see that cause it doesn't scroll to top, it only scroll up like 10px.. any idea what it might be?

Comment: Please check if there is any scripts conflict-ion. you can check it from browser consol.

Comment: Glad it helped you :) Cheers!!

Comment: It worked like a charm on Magento 2.2.3. Tks heaps!

Answer (score 4):

alternative solution:
check `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js` line: 100

```
$(document).trigger('ajax:addToCart', form.data().productSku);
```

We could add a custom js file:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Catalog/js/view/minicart-open": {}
    }
}
```

In the js:

```
$(document).on('ajax:addToCart', function () {#code here...}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can use this code in you minicart.phtml below of your templating code. I am using this code and it working for better. you can try it. Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery'], function ($) {
        $('.minicart-wrapper').on('contentLoading', function (event) {
            $('[data-block="minicart"]').on('contentUpdated', function () {
                $('[data-block="minicart"]').find('[data-role="dropdownDialog"]').dropdownDialog("open");
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('[data-block="minicart"]').find('[data-role="dropdownDialog"]').dropdownDialog("close");
                }, 4000);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks its Working... I want to learn Magento JS flow. How it works please share some link

Answer (score 1):

This above answer works but is missing the closing brace:

```
            $('[data-block="minicart"]').on('contentLoading', function (event) {
            addToCartCalls++;
            self.isLoading(true);
                $('[data-block="minicart"]').on('contentUpdated', function ()  {
                    $('[data-block="minicart"]').find('[data-role="dropdownDialog"]').dropdownDialog("open");

                setTimeout(function() {
                $('[data-block="minicart"]').find('[data-role="dropdownDialog"]').dropdownDialog("close");
                }, 4000);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working for Magento 2.3?

I have done the module as suggested but it still not opening the minicart.