# Show Pop Up when click on Add to cart Magento 2

Tags: magento2, addtocart, popup

**Is there any mistake in this code or file structure ?**
[link i followed](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123329/pop-up-minicart-when-i-add-a-product-to-the-cart-magento-2/140569)

**what i did**

`1)app/code/SomeName/AddCartPopUp/registration.php`

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'SomeName_AddCartPopUp',
    __DIR__
);
```

`2)app/code/SomeName/AddCartPopUp/view/frontend/default.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="1column">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
  <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="minicart.autoopen" template="SomeName_AddCartPopUp::minicart_open.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

`3)app/code/SomeName/AddCartPopUp/view/frontend/template/minicart_open.phtml`

```
 <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
         "[data-block='minicart']" : {
            "SomeName_AddCartPopUp/js/view/minicart_open" : {}
         }
    }
    </script>
```

`4)app/code/SomeName/AddCartPopUp/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart_open.js`

```
define(["jquery/ui","jquery"], function(Component, $){
    return function(config, element){
        var minicart = $(element);
        minicart.on('contentLoading', function () {
            minicart.on('contentUpdated', function () {
                minicart.find('[data-role="dropdownDialog"]').dropdownDialog("open");
            });
        });
    }
});
```

`5)app/code/SomeName/AddCartPopUp/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

</config>
```

`6)app/code/SomeName/AddCartPopUp/etc/module.xml`

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
        <module name="SomeName_AddCartPopUp" setup_version="1.0.0"></module>
            <sequence>
                <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
                 <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
                <module name="Magento_Quote"/>
                <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>>
            </sequence>
    </config>
```

Comment: do you want minicart open when a user click on add to cart button

Comment: yes, when user click add to cart pop must show that product is added

Comment: have you extended your theme like this : '/app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml'

Comment: no, i am using luma as default,there is no app/design/*

Comment: you must extended your theme , either using luma or any other theme

Comment: ok, without extending my module won't work ?

Comment: no that can work , but I am advised by  experts to extend the theme so you don't change any original files , I am posting the answer , how I did and that can help you as well , need to extend theme for that ...

Comment: how to achieve sir ?

Comment: always extend your theme and then try below solution , works and given you working link

Comment: let me know if any problem ?

Answer (score 3):

**Adding popup to minicart** when click on `add to cart` button

Edit your extended `default.xml`

```
/app/design/frontend/vendor-name/theme-name/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
```

and paste this line of code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>


            <!--minicart popup-->
        <referenceContainer name="content">
          <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="minicart.autoopen" template="Magento_Checkout::minicart_open.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>



    </body>
</page>
```

Now create and place template (`minicart_open.phtml`) file at below location.

```
/app/design/frontend/vendor-name/theme-name/Magento_Checkout/templates/minicart_open.phtml
```

and use this code in `minicart_open.phtml`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar */
?>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
     "[data-block='minicart']" : {
        "Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart_open" : {}
     }
}
</script>
```

Then create and add Js ( `minicart_open.js` ) file

```
/app/design/frontend/vendor-name/theme-name/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/minicart_open.js
```

paste below code inside file

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
define(["jquery/ui","jquery"], function(Component, $){
    return function(config, element){
        var minicart = $(element);
        minicart.on('contentLoading', function () {
            minicart.on('contentUpdated', function () {
                minicart.find('[data-role="dropdownDialog"]').dropdownDialog("open");

                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('[data-block="minicart"]').find('[data-role="dropdownDialog"]').dropdownDialog("close");
                }, 6000);


            });
        });
    }


});
```

All done , Keep cache disabled or clear and run below commands if needed

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Thanks

Comment: this one is working but when you add 2 or more than items it hangs your system. I checked in js code it's called many times after item add to cart. anyone have facing issue like that?

Comment: this is show popup AFTER item has added to card, not WHEN added to cart tho